# Android - SQLite limitations

Tags: android, database, sqlite

are there any restrictions for Android SQLite databases? I mean this - is it possible to have databases on SD card? Any restriction of max number of tables per database? Restriction of max size of a DB, or any other?

Thanks

Comment: [SQLite Limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: Does is apply for SQLite in android too or only "desktop" version are invovlved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing by http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db:

Android provides full support for SQLite databases

Additional note:
"Android does not impose any limitations beyond the standard SQLite concepts. We do recommend including an autoincrement value key field that can be used as a unique ID to quickly find a record. This is not required for private data, but if you implement a content provider, you must include a unique ID using the BaseColumns._ID constant."

So just be wary of standard SQLite limitations.