# Content storage for a publication app

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I am trying to develop a native application for a monthly magazine by fetching the content from their website pages. I will have the URLs of the articles that will get me the content. The content (mostly text, some pictures) will be refreshed once a month and stored locally in the device.

The choice of a native app is because I want a good user experience with respect to text rendering and non-dependence on internet connectivity.

My question is -- what is the best way to store it? Should I keep the content in files on the device or use Sqlite?

If there are any suggestions or somewhere I am going wrong at a fundamental level, please do suggest.

Thanks!
ak

Answer (score 1):

I always use sqlite on my android apps (and ios also by the way)

I use Rest concept, pretty much I download what I want for that moment according to my business and work locally with data in sqlite, from time to time I connect again to sync the info (downloading new stuff and uploading from sqlite)

By the way, for images, usually I store in sqlite as Blob datatype, unless there is a specific condition in my business that I would store in the file system or pull using http from internet

Comment: Thanks Poet. One doubt: a typical article that I will download could go for as long as 8000 words. Is sqlite okay for that kind of content?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this answer too - [Android - SQLite limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188921/android-sqlite-limitations) - which cites this from the Android Developers document:

> Android does not impose any limitations beyond the standard SQLite
>   concepts.

However, if you find that managing such large data inside Sqlite is not much interesting, you can try something like this:

```
table_pages:
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+
|  _id   |    mag_id   |   page_num  |       page_path_to_file      |
+========+=============+=============+==============================+
|   1    |    jun13    |      01     |   /sdcard/mag/jun13/01.json  |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

Simply put: **store your files (text+images) in disk, and index them in sqlite.** That's all.